# How to update a single column of a 2d tf.Variable?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Let's say I've got a MxN-shaped `tf.Variable` which stores some state of my custom layer:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
m, n = 3, 4  # just for example
v = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([m, n]), trainable=False)

# v = <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(3, 4) dtype=float32, numpy=
#     array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
#            [0., 0., 0., 0.],
#            [0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>
```

I am aware that I could update the values of this variable with `v.assign(...)`, but how can I update just a sub-section of this variable? For example, I would like to insert a given vector at a given column.

```py
x = tf.ones([m,1])
c = tf.Variable(2)
# update v by inserting x at column c
```

...such that the following would be the new values of `v`:

```py
# v = <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(3, 4) dtype=float32, numpy=
#     array([[0., 0., 1., 0.],
#            [0., 0., 1., 0.],
#            [0., 0., 1., 0.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with TF 2.2

```
m, n = 3, 4  # just for example
v = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([m, n]), trainable=False)
x = tf.ones(m)
c = 2

change_v = v[:,c].assign(x)
```